# \leqslant and \geqslant with unicode-math

Tags: unicode-math

I prefer the slanted version of `\leq` and `\geq`, so I usually set `\let\leq=\leqslant` somewhere in my style file or in the preamble. However, I noticed a weird behavior when I use LuaLaTex/XeLaTeX and `unicode-math`. Apparently, the command `\let\leq=\leqslant` is ineffective unless I put it after `\begin{document}`.

Is there a command (to put in the preamble or in a `.sty` file) to make `unicode-math` use the slanted version?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\let\leq=\leqslant

\begin{document}
% \let\leq=\leqslant % It works if I uncomment this
We write $x\leq y$
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\AtBeginDocument{\let\leq=\leqslant}`  as `unicode-math` delays all its settings

Comment: https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/465

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `C:\texlive\2023\texmf-dist\tex\latex\unicode-math\unicode-math-xetex.sty`, you can find

```latex
\group_begin:
  \file_get:nnN {unicode-math-table.tex} {} \l__um_mathtable_tl
  \cs_set:Npn \UnicodeMathSymbol #1#2#3#4
    {
      \exp_not:n { \__um_sym:nnn {#1} {#2} {#3} }
    }
  \tl_gset:Nx \g__um_mathtable_tl {\l__um_mathtable_tl}
\group_end:
\__um_cs_new:Nn \__um_input_math_symbol_table: {\g__um_mathtable_tl}
\AtBeginDocument{\__um_define_math_chars:}
\__um_cs_new:Nn \__um_define_math_chars:
 {
  \group_begin:
    \cs_set:Npn \__um_sym:nnn ##1##2##3
     {
      \tl_if_in:nnT
       { \mathord \mathalpha \mathbin \mathrel \mathpunct \mathop \mathfence }
       {##3}
      {
        \exp_last_unbraced:NNx \cs_gset_eq:NN ##2 { \char_generate:nn {##1} {12} }
      }
     }
    \__um_input_math_symbol_table:
  \group_end:
 }
```

`unicode-math-table.tex` is set in `\AtBeginDocument`.

---

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\AtBeginDocument{\let\leq=\leqslant}
\begin{document}
We write $x\leq y$
\end{document}
```

[image]